# Split vector to the characters and return a vector with single letters in R

Tags: r

I am beginner in R and I would like to ask you, I need to create a function that splits a vector to the characters and then print a vector with single "letters".

For example:

> "Hello" ... "H","e","l","l","o"
>
> 1435 ... 1,4,3,5

I can not use a strsplit function.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be to use `strsplit("hello","")[[1]]`.
A numeric string could be splitted as `strsplit(as.character(12345),"")[[1]]`.

Since you requested something else than `strsplit`, you could do something like

```
string <- "hello"
substring(string, 1:nchar(string), 1:nchar(string))
#[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one question yet. I need to create function which find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digits number. I need use strsplit function. Can you help me?